# Hotstrings to create spaces, em dashes, and bullet points for Google Sheets

Tags: autohotkey

I am a new to using AutoHotKey, and really I am trying to use it for one specific purpose. Right now I use Google Sheets to take notes, but the problem with it is that to create em dashes, bullet points, and space I have to use multiple keys. To create spacing between lines in a cell requires the combination CTRL+Enter, em dashes require Alt+0151, and bullet points require Alt+7.

So far, I have tried the following:

1. To create spaces I have tried both `Home::^+Enter`, `Home::<^+Enter`, and `Home::<LCtrl+Enter`. On the first combo (`Home::^+Enter`), the script runs but when I hit the `Home` key, nothing happens. On the second combo (`Home::<^+Enter`), the script runs but instead of creating a space in the cell like I want it to, it instead inputs `<`. On the third combo (`Home::<^LCtrl+Enter`) I get the following error message: "Error: This line does not contain a recognized action."
2. To create bullet points, I have tried `PgUp::!+0151` and `PgUp::Alt+0151`. In both cases, they give me the "This line does not contain a recognized action" error.
3. To create em dashes I have tried `PgDn::!+7`as well as `PgDn::Alt+7` but with the same "line does not contain a recognized action" error.

I realize these are very simple errors, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me get these working?

Comment: Note that the `+` in `Home::^+Enter` is the shift-key. Does `Home::Send , ^{enter}` work?

Comment: @EJE that did the trick, thanks. Any advice on the other two key combos for em dashes and bullet points?

Comment: It's similar for the bullet points, `PgDn::Send , !7`. There are two options for the em dash, `PgUp::Send , {alt down}0151{alt up}` or you can send the character directly, `PgUp::Send , {U+2014}`.

Comment: It looks like the em dash code you provided here worked, but no luck with the bullet point. I also tried ```PgUp::Send , !{7}``` but it did not work. Do you know why this would happen?
Edit: Nevermind, got it. The code ```PgUp::Send , {U+2022}``` worked for the bulletpoint.

Comment: Ah, I thought alt+7 was some way of toggling on/off bullets, but you just wanted the symbol. In that case, `PgUp::Send , !{NumPad7}` should work similar to your solution using unicode.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately Google Sheets doesn't support bullet points, so it has to be the symbol. This solution works well, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for this is as follows:

1. `Home::Send , ^{enter}` for space
2. `PgUp::Send , {U+2022}` for bullet point
3. `PgDn::Send , {U+2014}` for em dash

Answer (score -1):

Using ASCII characters works fine for me:

```
^2::
Send, {alt down}{Numpad2}{Numpad5}{Numpad0}{alt up}
```

For space and dash, change the combination to 32 and 45, respectively.

Here I'm using a hotkey (ctrl+2), not a hotstring, though.

Comment: Note that this particular hotkey might be busy, if "compatible shortcuts" (or something similar, don't remember what they called it) is enabled.